# Extended elements in a schema (using xs:redefine) have the wrong namespace when imported into a third schema

Tags: visual-studio, xsd, biztalk, biztalk-2013

Here is the scenario. I am in the process of implementing an ESB using BizTalk, I have a schema that I am using as a Process Header for messages going through BizTalk. The header schema is imported into all canonical schemas. The process header elements are promoted and used for routing. This approach works well. But now I want to extent this original process header schema for certain message types. I thought I would use xs:redefine to modify the main process header and add additional elements. But when I import the redefined schema into the canonical schema the new process header elements take the namespace of the canonical schema instead of the namespace of the process header schema that it extends.
Here are some simplified examples of what is happening:
1. OriginalProcessSchema.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:mh="http://ProcessHeaderNamespace" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ProcessHeaderNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MessageHeader" type="mh:ProcessHeader">

  </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="ProcessHeader">
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Field1" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Field2" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

2.ExtendedProcessHeaderSchema.xsd - the one which redefines the first one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:mh="http://ProcessHeaderNamespace" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ProcessHeaderNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:redefine schemaLocation=".\OriginalProcessSchema.xsd">
    <xs:complexType name="ProcessHeader">
      <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
        <xs:extension base="mh:ProcessHeader">
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Field3" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
      </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:redefine>
</xs:schema>
```

3.CanonicalSchema.xsd - This imports the second schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" xmlns="http://ProductNamespace" xmlns:ph="http://ProcessHeaderNamespace" targetNamespace="http://ProductNamespace" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import schemaLocation=".\ExtendedProcessHeaderSchema.xsd" namespace="http://ProcessHeaderNamespace" />
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <b:references>
        <b:reference targetNamespace="http://ProcessHeaderNamespace" />
      </b:references>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Product">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="ProcessHeader" type="ph:ProcessHeader" />
        <xs:element name="ProductDate">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Field4" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Field5" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="Field6" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If I generate an instance of the second file in visual studio all looks good, all elements are in the same namespace:

```
<ns0:MessageHeader xmlns:ns0="http://ProcessHeaderNamespace">
  <ns0:Field1>Field1_0</ns0:Field1>
  <ns0:Field2>Field2_0</ns0:Field2>
  <ns0:Field3>Field3_0</ns0:Field3>
</ns0:MessageHeader>
```

However if I generate an instance of the third file, this is what I see:

```
<ns0:Product xmlns:ns0="http://ProductNamespace">
  <ProcessHeader>
    <ns1:Field1 xmlns:ns1="http://ProcessHeaderNamespace">ph:Field1_0</ns1:Field1>
    <ns1:Field2 xmlns:ns1="http://ProcessHeaderNamespace">ph:Field2_0</ns1:Field2>
    <ns0:Field3>Field3_0</ns0:Field3>
  </ProcessHeader>
  <ProductDate>
    <Field4>Field4_0</Field4>
    <Field5>Field5_0</Field5>
    <Field6>Field6_0</Field6>
  </ProductDate>
</ns0:Product>
```

Field3 is in the namespace of the Product canonical (ProductNamespace in this example). I am expecting it to be in the ProcessHeader namespace. A colleague has looked at this with a different tool (oXygen xml) and indeed the namespace of all elements in the process header is the same. So is this a bug in Visual Studio / Biztalk? Can anyone shed any light on what is happening here or provide a fix for this?

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and BizTalk Server 2013

Comment: Are you creating these schemas yourself?  Or is this a standard you're trying to implement?  I ask because, based on the question, you are at risk for *significantly* over complicating your implementation.

Comment: Yes we are creating the schemas and yes it is a standard we are trying to implement. The idea is we have a generic process header for all messages and then if necessary have a way of extending it.

Comment: Can I ask what standard?  I've seen a lot of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'll Answer the question this way.  You solve this problem by not even trying to do this.

Meaning, trying to create an 'extensible' schema framework is more trouble than it's worth.  cXml, ebXml, etc. all do this and they are *crazy, stupidly difficult to work with*.

This **unnecessary and expensive complication** is a huge reason (IMO) why JSON took off the way it did.

Using one **xs:include** for the header is all I would even consider, using the **Empty Namespace**.

I wrote about this with BizTalk here: [BizTalk: Simplify BizTalk Dev by Using the Empty Namespace](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/35484.biztalk-simplify-biztalk-dev-by-using-the-empty-namespace.aspx)